# LZMA Or 7zip in Delphi

Tags: delphi, 7zip, lzma

Is there any Library in Delphi to handle LZMA (or 7zip)files including creating self extracting EXEs

There are some sources code at [7zip.org](http://www.7zip.org)in (c++ java c#) but i want them in delphi

BUT i want something which is stand alone (No DLLs)

Comment: JFYI: we have this in the plans for SecureBlackbox 9, which is planned for spring. Not exactly what you'd like to hear, yes, so not an answer but a comment.

Comment: i need the reason for -1

Comment: i saw your comment "i am in a process of making self extractor" - do you know this: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/create-a-sfx-file-with-delphi-self-extracting-archives/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are two solutions:

1) use the into native pascal translated sdk:

[Pascal LZMA SDK](http://www.birtles.org.uk/programming/)

[Source Download](http://www.birtles.org.uk/programming/LZMA.442b.7z)

2) you can compile the c version of the sdk into obj files and link them to your delphi project. this one requires a translation of the header files to delphi and it requires lots of c knowledge.

[LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)

Comment: 3) you can translate the current C lib to Pascal again, so that we don't have an old version in pascal anymore, and fix the x86isms while you at it for FPC's sake ( :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Inno setup have delphi source code to encode and decode lzma.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php

you could also simply use inno setup to create your self extractor.

Comment: That version uses c compiled object files which are linked into the delphi project.

Answer (score 2):

try http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13 it might be what you need

Comment: Its good for general purpose ! but i am in a process of making self extractor !!   so dll may be a bit problem but still can be used

Comment: in 7z install directory there is .sfx files, simply append the file with your 7z stream and it will works.

Answer (score 2):

[JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) has JclCompression library which support 7zip and there's [Delphi 7 Zip API](http://code.google.com/p/d7zip/) both of them are open source project.

Answer (score 0):

A patch for Delphi Zip that support both LZMA and Zip64 is ready: [delphi-zip](https://github.com/ccy/delphi-zip)