# Delphi LZMA Decompression sample

Tags: delphi, lzma

I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344976/lzma-or-7zip-in-delphi) thread link of the [delphi-zip](https://github.com/ccy/delphi-zip) library that has implementation of LZMA. But I can't make proper use of Decompression from it. 
Can some one write a little decompression sample for me, using this library?

Here is my code, it works for compression but didn't work for decompression and return 0 size

uses System.Zip.LZMA;

....

```
procedure TForm2.CompressProgress(Sender: TObject; const aPosition, aSize, aCompressedSize: UInt64);
begin
end;

procedure TForm2.DecompressProgress(Sender: TObject; const aPosition, aSize: UInt64);
begin
end;

procedure TForm2.CompressButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var LZI: TLZMAEncoderStream;  OutStream, InStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
     OutStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
     LZI := TLZMAEncoderStream.Create(OutStream,  CompressProgress);
     InStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
     InStream.LoadFromFile('1.exe');
     InStream.Position := 0;
     LZI.Write(InStream, InStream.Size);
     OutStream.Position := 0;
     OutStream.SaveToFile('1.exe.lzma');
     InStream.Free;
     OutStream.Free;
     LZI.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.DecompressButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Deca: TLZMADecoderStream;    Str1: TMemoryStream; S2 : TBytesStream;  J, I: Cardinal;
begin
    I := 0;
    Str1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Str1.LoadFromFile('1.exe.lzma');
    Str1.Position := 0;
    Deca:= TLZMADecoderStream.Create(Str1, DecompressProgress);

   S2   := TBytesStream.Create;
   J := Deca.Read(S2.Bytes, 0, i);

    Caption := IntToStr(J);

   S2.Position := 0;
   S2.SaveToFile('1.exe');

   Deca.Free;
   Str1.Free;
   S2.Free;
end;
```

also I tried do like this, but still not work

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Deca: TLZMADecoderStream;    Str1 : TMemoryStream;  S2:TBytesStream;  J, I: Cardinal;
begin
    I := 0;
    Str1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Str1.LoadFromFile('1.exe.lzma');
    Str1.Position := 0;
    Deca:= TLZMADecoderStream.Create(Str1, DeProgress);

   S2   := TBytesStream.Create;
   Deca.Position := 0;
   J := Deca.Read(S2.Bytes, 0, Deca.Size);
   Caption := IntToStr(J);
   S2.Position := 0;
   S2.SaveToFile('Dec0.exe');
   Deca.Free;
   Str1.Free;
   S2.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You read 0 bytes from the decomp stream, what did you expect would happen?!

Comment: `J := Deca.Read(S2.Bytes, 0, i);`. You initialized `I := 0;`, never changed it, and therefore read zero bytes from the stream. You got exactly what you asked for, AFAICT.

Comment: So I guess you need to run a loop reading chunks until Read returns 0. You also do what so many Delphi programmers do and feel compelled to use memory streams at all costs. You are reading a file? Use a TFileStream. Don't read it all into memory first. When decompressing why would you read into a byte stream, and then save to file. Read directly into a file stream that is opened in write mode. Streams are an abstraction layer.

Comment: May be you can give a sample pleas )

Comment: I'm sure you can set I to a non zero value.

Comment: Yes, but if I set it to Deca.size nothing happens :( Im also changed TStream to MemoryStream in the System.Zip.LZMA

Comment: No. Don't make changes there. Roll that back and learn that you don't have to use memory streams for everything.

Comment: Why not give a help with code if you know how ?

Comment: I've written you some code. I've used it to successfully compress and decompress a text file. I think you've chosen the wrong library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked to read zero bytes and that's what you got. You will need to loop reading chunks of data out of the stream. Keep looping until `Read` returns zero. Remember that `Read` returns the number of bytes read.

I'd use functions like this:

```
procedure LZMAcompress(InStream, OutStream: TStream);
var
  Encoder: TLZMAEncoderStream;
begin
  Encoder := TLZMAEncoderStream.Create(OutStream, nil);
  try
    Encoder.Write(InStream, InStream.Size);
  finally
    Encoder.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure LZMAdecompress(InStream, OutStream: TStream; Count: Int64);
const
  BufferSize = 1024*1024;
var
  Decoder: TLZMADecoderStream;
  Buffer: TBytes;
  BytesRead, BytesToRead: Integer;
begin
  Decoder := TLZMADecoderStream.Create(InStream, nil);
  try
    SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize);
    repeat
      BytesToRead := Min(Count, BufferSize);
      BytesRead := Decoder.Read(Buffer, BytesToRead);
      OutStream.Write(Buffer, BytesRead);
      dec(Count, BytesRead);
    until Count=0;
  finally
    Decoder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And there's absolutely no need for memory streams here. Two file streams are what is needed.

The big issue that you will face is that the library you have chosen to use requires you to know how large the file is that you are decompressing. If you try to read more bytes than are available, then this library code enters a non-terminating loop. Hence my `Count` parameter in `LZMAdecompress`.

My suspicion is that the library that you have chosen to use, or at least the classes that you have chosen to use, are ill suited to your needs. I've only had a quick look through the code but it doesn't look good to me. Any compression library that has a non-terminating loop when presented with invalid data is not very useful. I would shun this library on this evidence. If I were you I would call the LZMA C API directly.

Perhaps your other problem is that you have made erroneous changes to the library that you are using. Don't do that. Go back to the original version from github.

Comment: Thank you David! ))) Realy helpful for dude like me with low skill