# Decompression of memorystreams using LZMA

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, memorystream, compression, lzma

I have a Remote Administration Tool and was necessary change for 64 bits plattform. I have used Zlib for compress and decompress memorystreams, but after do this change, Zlib classes [showed several errors when I tried compile my project in 64 bits plattform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGE8s.png), because Zlib only is avaiable for 32 bits plattform.

Then,I  had that search on internet for some similar classes for make compress and decompress of memorystreams and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355553/delphi-lzma-decompression-sample) where discussion is about LZMA class that also can make like I need, similar to Zlib class.

And I understood the advice:

> The big issue that you will face is that the library you have chosen to use requires you to know how large the file is that you are decompressing.

So, I'm here exactly for know some suggestion for try solve this trouble.

In others words, I want know how decompress exactly the size of memorystream that is received by Server side of my project?

Any opinion or suggestion here is welcome.

Comment: Q: What specific compile errors did you get?  Q: What version of Delphi are you using?  Please update your post with this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it looks like you're using ZLibEX, by Roberto Della Pasqua, Borland:

- https://github.com/senjaxus/Delphi_Remote_Access_PC/blob/master/Fontes%20Access%20PC%20-%20Delphi%207/Cliente/ZLIBEX.pas

You're correct - the assembly portion `MoveI32` is non-portable.

BUT ...

You should be able to use the *same* API in your current Delphi XE-5 from `System.Zlib`:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.ZLib
- http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/native-zip-file-support-in-delphi-xe2
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/ZLibCompressDecompress_%28Delphi%29